# Why does my dynamic javascript highlight form break?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to build a simple html form that highlights text in yellow on a page by wrapping it in a span on keyup of the form (using jquery).

It works fine until I backspace on the keyboard to fully clear the contents of the form, then it stops working. I've created a quick codepen to demonstrate my issue:

http://codepen.io/liamtarpey/pen/KefCx

It's probably a very simple fix but I can't get my head around what's going wrong, does anyone know what the issue is?

I'd really like to use the 'body' or 'html' selector rather than '*' as it affects the head of my page too but I can't get it to work with either of these.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="searchfor"/>
</form>
<!-- The below is just a test to check the value of the input is being returned -->
<span>Value of form: </span><span id="test"></span>

<div>
  <h3>example text here</h3>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#searchfor").on("keyup change", function() {

  // store value in a variable
  value = this.value;

  // unwrap span from previous search
  $("span[id^='highlightspan']").contents().unwrap();

  // wrap span around inputted text
  $("*").each(function() { 
    if($(this).children().length==0) { 
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(value, '<span id="highlightspan" style="background:yellow;">' + value + '</span>')); 
    } 
  });

  $("#test").html(value);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `highlightspan` elements after you unwrap them:

```
  $("span[id^='highlightspan']").contents().unwrap();
  $("span[id^='highlightspan']").remove();
```

This will prevent duplicate IDs on the DOM, however it may be best to just make `highlightspan` a class.

**Example** 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rIujD

Comment: Hi Kevin, this just deletes the text I've searched for off my page completely, I don't really want to do that...

Comment: @LiamTarpey Please see updated code pen, I posted the wrong link.

Answer (score 0):

***[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/HV4xe/)***

```
if (value === '') {
    $('#highlightspan').remove();
}
```

You need to remove `highlightspan`, so again to add it in this code `$(this).html($(this).html().replace(value, '<span id="highlightspan" style="background:yellow;">' + value + '</span>'));`